# cp command: Overwrite confirmation with file diff

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash

When running `cp` command to copy files, I would like to be prompted for overwrite confirmation, and, if possible, view the file diff confirming.

Is this possible? And if yes, how?

Ideal example:

```
$ cp file1.txt file2.txt
0a1,2
> 1.
> 
2a5,6
> 2.
> 
4a9,10
> 3.
> 
Overwrite file2.txt? [Yes/No/Keep both] (default Y):
```

Comment: This can be easily done with a script. Before providing an answer: what do you want done in case the files are binary?

Comment: I do not plan to use on binary files, but I guess a simple "binaries differ" info would be enough. Script.. I hoped there was some way to do it with cp parameters or another built-in command.

Comment: Have you looked at the manual for `cp`?

Comment: Shell scripts basically *combine* built-in commands, so to speak :-)

Comment: I'd recommend using a different command name (not `cp`) -- this is a significantly different function, and using the same name is likely to cause mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placing alias commands in your bash profile will gain you partial overwrite protection. As others mentioned in your comments, you will need to write a script add the diff function.

I placed the commands below in my `~/.bash_profile`.

Bash on macOS determines what file is your bash profile in this order:

1. `~/.bash_profile`
2. `~/.bash_login`
3. `~/.profile`

These commands tell cp, mv and rm to give you a warning when a file is to be overwritten or deleted:

```
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'
alias rm='rm -i'
# Placing a blank after sudo causes alias substitution 
# for sudo's inner commands . See Gordon Davisson's comments below for 
# details. 
alias sudo='sudo '
```

This example, assumes you have placed the above commands in your bash profile.

```
mac $ touch a
mac $ touch aa
mac $ cp aa a
overwrite a? (y/n [n]) n
not overwritten
mac RC=1   $ rm a
remove a? 
mac $ mv aa a
overwrite a? (y/n [n]) n
not overwritten
# demonstrate sudo protection
mac $ touch inin
mac $ sudo cp inin hihi
overwrite hihi? (y/n [n]) n
not overwritten
mac RC=1   $ sudo mv  inin hihi
overwrite hihi? (y/n [n]) n
not overwritten
mac $ sudo rm inin hihi
remove inin? y
remove hihi? y
mac $
```

These alias command do not protect you in all circumstances like when you invoke a new shell or run cp, mv or rm from within other commands like find.

---

**P.S.**: The aliases mentioned above use the same name as the original command, thereby shadowing it. To access the original un-aliased command, prepend it with a `\` character (E.g., `\cp`, `\mv`, `\rm` etc.).

Comment: If you alias `sudo` to itself with a space at the end (i.e. `alias sudo='sudo '`), the shell will expand aliases after it and these protections will be applied after `sudo` (i.e. `sudo mv ...` would expand to `sudo mv -i ...`). But this won't apply them in other contexts, such as `find ... -exec mv ...`, or when you open a root shell with `sudo -i` or `sudo su`.

Comment: I didn't know about the \ prefix! Great